# Firebase Cloud Messaging generate a new Sender ID

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm implementing a Java Server App to connect to the FCM Server using the XMPP connection. In the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/server#connecting) it tells me that I should use a different FCM sender ID to avoid any risks of sending test messages to production users or sending upstream messages from production traffic over test connections.

But I can't seem to find this option in Firebase Console. I can only create a new Server key. Any ideas?

Comment: @AmiHollander did you understood my question? I want a new Sender ID not a key in the Firebase Database. This is about server side app. Please kindly read the link I've posted and the question.

Comment: Were you able to find solution for this? According to this document https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref under "Mismatched Sender" document says - `When a client app registers for FCM, it must specify which senders are allowed to send messages. You should use one of those sender IDs when sending messages to the client app. If you switch to a different sender, the existing registration tokens won't work`. This means that FCM allows multiple sender IDs but it does not document how to register multiple senders.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A SenderID is permanent per project. You can't create several sender ids for a single project. Just create another FCM project for testing.

Comment: this doesn't make sens, here is the docs **"Regular testing on pre-production (a smaller environment where the latest CCS builds run) is beneficial for isolating real users from test code. Test devices and test code connecting to fcm-xmpp.googleapis.com:5236 should use a different FCM sender ID to avoid any risks of sending test messages to production users or sending upstream messages from production traffic over test connections."** why would they say that if it's not possible to get a test key

Comment: @RazvanCristianLung It's possible to have a new Sender Id by creating a different Firebase Project. It's the only way to get a different one, since (as indicated in the answer) a SenderID is permanent for each project (cannot be deleted, modified, or re-generated).

Answer (score 0):

In Firebase, the Sender ID is actually the **Firebase project ID,** which you **cannot change**. You can confirm this by comparing the Sender ID to the project_id in `google-services.json` or Firebase Project Settings. From now on, I think the Sender ID should just be though of as the project ID.

As with other Firebase services, you should have separate projects to isolate development, staging and production environments.